# Can not download from S3: Access Denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS Lambda function that takes an image file from an s3 bucket (trigger), removes
the background from the image and then sends it to another bucket.

I get the url of the removed background image in my node js back-end and send it to the front-end but when I want to show it in image tag an error `Access Denied` appears. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [mre], along with the exact error message you encouter.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're describing.  Please include specific errors verbatim as well as a precise description of the operations you're attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, if you access them over the https endpoints s3 objects are private. Which is most likely what is happening in your case. You have 2 ways of accomplishing what you want:

1- Make the bucket public through a bucket policy

```
{
  "Id": "PolicyNameThatYouSpecify",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadAccess",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This comes with its security flaws, as you may not want to make your content public.

2- Use presigned urls

With [presigned urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) in S3, you can give time limited access to your content without making them public permanently